# Cordova plugin for play locals 360VR Videos in Android and IOS

Tags: cordova, video, plugins, 360-virtual-reality

360VR videos like in youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzuqhhs6NWbgTzMuM09WKDQ

If you play this videos in a device and you move It you can surf the scene.

We only need a plugin for use in a cordova app. Even the Google video V3 API could do the work but the problem is We need play local videos in the APP.

We are still looking and testing but found nothing In the meantime We ask the question in case anyone knows any solution possible.

We are using Cordova + AngularJS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a number of HTML5 video players that support VR 360 video - this may be an easier approach that using a plugin.There is a detailed example here of how to use one open source player, dash.js in a cordova app: https://msopentech.com/blog/2015/03/06/using-dash-js-to-run-cordova-apps-within-azure-media-services/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Mick. I'll take a look at all that

Comment: Finally we are using an HTML5 player but our client start complain. Y very bad perfomance  solution. All free players based on three.js have a big problem on IOS. The cordova APP in ios close sometime because a problem about not allows renders opengl when app goes in background.

Comment: This is the well known problem comented by Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1766/_index.html Now we are out of date and must offer a solution our client and fix our app, big problem now. Please, anybody know a cordova pluging for play 360 panorama videos in ios  and android. Please.

Comment: What we are using is cordova webview with videojs as base video player and we added panorama plugin wich use  the three.js javascript lib.

Comment: This is our currently solution https://github.com/yanwsh/videojs-panorama. We must find a solution or use a native plugin for 360 panorama for cordova

Comment: Still testing a lot of  alternatives and  I start thinking Cordova cannot solve this  problem

Comment: @Falinsito, i know it's too late , did you find any solution for same ? thanks in advance.